# how do I wrap my menu in to sub menu using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[this is my site.](http://91.109.247.178/~brasseriegalway/)

[this is how I finally make it look like](http://uploadpie.com/Po7HH)

I want to divide the the menu list items into two sub menu say menu left and right. And then wrap them in a div. This is make it easy for me to style them and this way they would stay responsive as well.

Now, I have been trying to achieve this by

```
jQuery( ".menu-item-580", ".menu-item-583",".menu-item-584",".menu-item-563").wrapAll("<div class='new' />").after(".menubar-brand");
```

I have trying this in browser console.

I also tried same above code by using `appendTo()` instead of `after()`

But, still no luck.

Comment: Why are you attempting to use jQuery? do you not have control over the html and css?  I can give advice on the menu html and css, but would know what you need it to look like on mobile devices.

Comment: hi, thanks for responding.

Its a wordpress site. I do not have control over html. I have control over css. Thats why, I am trying to do it through jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you're basically doing this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
    <div class="new">
        <li>
        <li>
    </div>
    <li>
</ul>
```

which is not a valid markup.

The easiest way to goup `<li>`s would be to assign different additional css classes to different parts of the list:

```
<ul>
    <li class="group1">
    <li class="group1">
    <li class="group2">
    <li class="group2">
</ul>
```

Also, have a look at this: [Is there a way to group `<li>` elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958272/is-there-a-way-to-group-li-elements)